# Export Excel to PPT and random Picture from File

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

ok, so im stuck since a while and dont know how tackle this problem.

Situation: I have excel file with data where i filter down to the data that i want to export. There i already have a macro that exports me the selection to PowerPoint (and that works just fine).

Until now i have a dummy picture on the PPT slides that i have to change manually.
I want to change that.
I want to insert a random generator that inserts a random picture from a set of pictures in a folder on my pc on .

I do understand the basics of how a random generator works but im nowhere near understanding on how to apply that to my case, and where i have to insert the generator it into the code.

Here is my code for the excel to PPT.

```
Sub XLS_to_PPT()

Dim pptPres As Presentation
Dim strPfad As String
Dim strPOTX As String
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim strSave As String



strPfad = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
strPOTX = "Credential_PPT_Template.pptx"
strSave = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application


pptVorlage = strPfad & "\" & strPOTX

pptApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=pptVorlage, untitled:=msoTrue


Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation

For Each tableRow In Sheets("Credentials").ListObjects("Credential_Submission").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
Set newSlide = pptPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
newSlide.Shapes("PMOTeamSize").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(69).Value
newSlide.Shapes("TeamSize").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(65).Value
newSlide.Shapes("Header").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(4).Value
newSlide.Shapes("ClientChanlenge").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(75).Value
newSlide.Shapes("HowWeHelped").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(76).Value
newSlide.Shapes("ClientBenefitsDelivered").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = tableRow.Columns(77).Value


Next tableRow

pptPres.Slides(1).Delete

pptPres.SaveAs strSave & "\" & ("New_Request")



pptPres.Close

Set pptPres = Nothing
Set pptApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to understand you: Your question is about how to insert a random image from a folder, not about Excel into Powerpoint?

Comment: Yes, Im running the code Excel to PPT (that works) 
In the same instance when i create the PPT slide with the Information from the Excel i want to insert a random picture from File onto the same slide.

Comment: And your question is about how to pick a random image or how to insert a picture into powerpoint?

Comment: How to insert a random picture into powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

One of approach is:

```
Public Function GetRandImageFile(imFolder As String) As String
    Static list As Collection
    Static lastFolder As String
    
    If list Is Nothing Or lastFolder <> imFolder Then
        On Error GoTo out
        lastFolder = imFolder
        Set list = New Collection
        cnt = 0
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fd = fs.getfolder(lastFolder)
        For Each f In fd.Files
            pos = InStrRev(f.Name, ".")
            ext = ""
            If pos > 0 Then ext = LCase(Mid(f.Name, pos))
            Select Case ext
                Case ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp" ' and so on
                    list.Add f.Name, CStr(cnt)
                    cnt = cnt + 1
            End Select
        Next
    End If
    
    Randomize
    slash = IIf(Right(lastFolder, 1) <> "\", "\", "")
    GetRandImageFile = lastFolder & slash & list(Rnd() * (list.Count - 1) + 1)
out:
End Function
```

Comment: Careful, your index into `list` will generate values from 0 to list.Count - 1, but Collections start with index 1. And your random values are not evenly distributes as you (implicitly) use rounding rather that truncation.

Comment: Also to mention: Use `lCase` on `ext` to catch also files with Uppercase names. And you could use `ext = lcase(fs.GetExtensionName(f))`. And I would put the part that gets a random filename into a separate function.